# How to embed QlikSense app in web?

Tags: qliksense

Our web app is on Linux cloud and we use Qlik Sense as our visualization platform.

Can we embed Qlik Sense within a web page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Qlik Sense server is windows based so you would have to host that on a windows box.

Qlik Sense has two APIs that you can leverage as an entry point,
The Mashup API which allows you to embed visualizations from Qlik Sense https://help.qlik.com/sense/en-us/developer/index.html#../Subsystems/Workbench/Content/BuildingWebsites/mashups-introduction.htm

Or you could roll your own client/visualizations/interaction model by leveraging the QIX Engine API which is a RPC styled websocket API.

https://help.qlik.com/sense/en-us/developer/index.html#../Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/introducing-engine-API.htm%3FTocPath%3DQlik%2520Engine%2520API%7C_____0